# Using CALayer as a background for other NSViews

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I have an application with an NSTableView in a window. I want to use a CALayer as the background for the entire window, and the table view.  In all my my experiments so far, the CALayer always draws over the NSTableView, which is not the effect I'm looking for.  Is there a way to make this work, or am I simply out of luck due to the nature of layer-hosting views vs NSViews?

My test setup is a window with the usual NSScrollView/NSTableView combo, and a sibling NSView behind it in the view order. The NSView is set to be layer-hosting with my custom layer within it (just a layer with a backgroundColor set). I've experimented with setting the window's content view to be layer-backed, as well as the table view itself, as well as wrapping the NSScrollView in a layer-backed NSView. The result is always the same.

Thanks for any insight you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. all overlapping views or layers should be layer backing or layer hosting for correct ordering.

you can set `[tableview setWantsLayer:YES]`
or simply check it in the layers tab when editing the interface.

Comment: Have you tested this? In my tests with an NSScrollView/NSTableView, both set to be layer-backed, the CALayer still shows up on top of them.

Comment: have you tried to rearrange them after initialization? in awakeFromNib? for example you can send addSubview to theirs superview in correct order. and be sure that superview is also layer backed.